# implementing floating label on ion-searchbar and inconsistant color across devices (ios/android)

Tags: css, ionic-framework, cross-platform, ionic3

I'm working in ionic to make cross-platform applications, I want to implement floating labels to my input fields, I've implemented them by taking help [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#floating-labels) but I'm getting problem implementing floating labels to  ion-searchbar. I want to know is this even possible to implement floating labels on seachbar and if so how can we achieve it ? I've already searched about it and couldn't find anything.

Another thing which is inconsistent is how the floating labels are being shown on different devices (Android/iOS). Is there any way I can change label color when input field is focused in iOS. For android its handling it automatically (i.e. white color by as placeholder and becomes blue when it floats up) but in iPhone it stays black.

ionic version: **3.9.2**

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

********UPDATE********

I'm able to change the color of floating label when focused. Now is there any way to change this floating label differently for different labels ? Actually I have components with different backgrounds so same color won't work on all the components. I've tried to put the

```
$label-ios-text-color-focused: red;
```

but no effect on the label and its still taking color value from the variable.scss file.

Any help ?

Comment: It would be good if you could put your code over here. So that anybody can help you with that, or can help with any alternatives.

Comment: The code is exactly what I'm coping from the link I've given in question. I'm not getting any error in code, just want to know whether what I want to achieve is possible or not and how it would be achieved.

Comment: Which kind of option you need on floating labels when user clicks on ion-searchbar icon?

Comment: First thing -> I want to know is it possible to implement floating label on ion-searchbar ?
second thing -> How can I change color of floating label when input is focused (specially in iOS).

Answer (score 1):

For applying the color on the labels while input is focused ( specially in iOS)

```
$label-ios-text-color-focused : red;
```

Write this line in your variable.scss file

Comment: Thanks, Its working well on iOS. +1. Any solution for searchbar thing ?

Comment: I want to ask 1 more question, Is there anyway to implement different colors for different floating labels in same app ? Right now above mentioned line is making all the floating label white across the app. I want some labels in different colors. I tried adding same line in component's .scss file but it didn't work. Any workaround ?